# What is a better approach to deal with EventEmitter and cyclic requires?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have user service like that:

```
'use strict';

let events = require('services/events');

module.exports = {
    create: function (data) {
        doCreate(data).then(user => {
            events.emit('user.create');
        });
    },

    addBonus: function (transaction) {
        doSomething;
    }
}
```

And I have `events` module:

```
'use strict';

let EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
let pubsub = new EventEmitter();
let userService = require('services/user'); 

pubsub.on('user.create', function(user) {
    console.log('EVENT: user.create');
    doSomething();
}

pubsub.on('payment.success', function(transaction) {
   userService.addBonus(transaction); // check if it was first transaction then add bonus to user
}

module.exports = pubsub;
```

In this case code has cyclic requires and code doesn't work.

I think it's common when `events` module uses service which emit the event in this module. What is better approach to design this case? I have next ideas:

- create a few `events` modules classified by events type
- use constructor function in `user` service

Comment: Was this an a acceptable answer?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps break the code into multiple files:

```
// services/user/create
let events = require('services/events');
module.exports = {
    create: function (data) {
        doCreate(data).then(user => {
            events.emit('user.create');
        });
    },
}

// services/user/addBonus
module.exports = {
    addBonus: function (transaction) {
        doSomething;
    }
}

// services/events
let EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
let pubsub = new EventEmitter();
let userService = require('services/user/addBonus'); 

pubsub.on('user.create', function(user) {
    console.log('EVENT: user.create');
    doSomething();
}

pubsub.on('payment.success', function(transaction) {
   userService.addBonus(transaction); // check if it was first transaction then add bonus to user
}
```